# How do I write out a string whose length is dependent upon a user's entry's length?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, count, write-host

I'm writing a script that has a lot of output, and can take multiple computer names. The output announces the computer name, then a lot of info about that particular computer. I want to have a series of `#`s above and below where it announces the computer name before each section of info, but would like to see if I can have the amount of #s be the same as the length of the provided computer name(s). For example:

```
########
COMPNAME
########
```

or

```
##############
LONGERCOMPNAME
##############
```

I'd rather not have to have an if else for every possible case, such as

```
if ($compname.length -eq "8") {
  Write-Host "########"
  Write-Host "$compname"
  Write-Host "########"
} elseif ($compname -eq "9") {
  Write-Host "#########"
  Write-Host "$compname"
  Write-Host "#########"
```

and so on. If I have to, I will, it'd just be ten of those or so. Or I could just use some amount of `#`s that will always definitely cover at least the max length a computer name might be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're gonna love this feature of PowerShell.  You can "multiply" a string.

Try this:

```
$sep = '@'

Write-Output ($sep*5)

$names = "Hello World", "me too", "goodbye"

$names | % {
Write-Output ($sep*($_.Length))
Write-Output $_
Write-Output ($sep*($_.Length))
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
@@@@@
@@@@@@@@@@@
Hello World
@@@@@@@@@@@
@@@@@@
me too
@@@@@@
@@@@@@@
goodbye
@@@@@@@
```

Comment: Thank you, Kory! This is exactly what I was looking for. I've changed my mind a little about the formatting I want to use, but this answers my question perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
$NbChar=5


#method 1 (best)
'@' * $NbChar

#method 2
New-Object  System.String "@", $NbChar

#method 3
-join (1..$NbChar | %{"@"})

#method 4
"".PadLeft($NbChar, '@')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend wrapping [Kory Gill](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42035063/1630171)'s suggestion in a custom function, so that you have an easy way of formatting any given name:

```
function Format-ComputerName([string]$ComputerName) {
  $separator = '#' * $ComputerName.Length
  '{0}{1}{2}{1}{0}' -f $separator, [Environment]::NewLine, $ComputerName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or a fixed-width banner:

```
"{0}`r`n# {1,-76} #`r`n{0}" -f ('#' * 80), $compname;
```

e.g.:

```
################################################################################
# LONGERCOMPNAME                                                               #
################################################################################
```

You can also add dates, times, Etc.:

```
"{0}`r`n# {1:G} : {2,-54} #`r`n{0}" -f ('#' * 80), (Get-Date), $compname;
```

e.g.:

```
################################################################################
# 04/02/2017 16:42:07 : LONGERCOMPNAME                                         #
################################################################################
```

More info on string formatting [here](http://powershellprimer.com/html/0013.html)